# C# .net Core reconnect to Oracle after database enabled

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

#### Problem is how to reconnect to database Oracle after troubles

I have .net Core web-api project in docker, where I connect to Oracle database. For connecting I use nugget package [oracleClientCore](https://github.com/ericmend/oracleClientCore-2.0)

How I connect and call stoted procedure:

```
string cs = "Data Source = 172.10.200.100:1521/dev;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=test; Password=devtest;";
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(cs)){
  connection.Open();
  using (OracleCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_check_db";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
  }
}
```

*In stored procedure `sp_check_db` just make `insert into table`*

Sometimes the connection to database falling down and I got exception `ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE`. After the database was enabled again I continue to receive same error `ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE` till I rebuild and redeploy the project.

What can I do in this situation, it's not right behavior?
Something wrong with my code or connection string?

Comment: @MarcusHöglund It's my imaginary IP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your application is dependent on external integrations (in this case your db) which can be unreachable for small periods of time due to patches, network failare etc, its
suitable to implement an retry policy. The retry logic will, depend on how you configure it, rerun the code a certain of time if a specific exception occours.

Here's an example of how to implement a simple retry logic with the framework [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry) which will rerun your code three times in a ten second span if an exception containing the `ORA-03114` occours. If the code still throws the same exception after the third time the exception will go throw.

```
var retryTimes = 3;
var waitBetweenExceptions = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<OracleException>(e => e.Message.Contains("ORA-03114"))
    .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, i => waitBetweenExceptions);

await retryPolicy.Execute(() =>
{
    string cs = "Data Source = 172.10.200.100:1521/dev;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=test; Password=devtest;";
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(cs)){
      connection.Open();
      using (OracleCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) 
      {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_check_db";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: It's good answer and I'll use this code, but it isn't that I expected - error happens when already database enabled for calling sp - and anly rebuild and redeploy project helps me - maybe we can reset connection?

Comment: @IgorCova this might has something to do with the docker container configuration rather then on how you call the oracle db

Comment: Well, then I need to investigate the problem deeper. and at the moment Your answer is correct if we think that the connection problem occurred at the time of calling api